# Angular JS: Route provider controller method not called?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have just started learning Angular, and when I tried using Route provider:

```
var App1 = angular.module('App1',['ngRoute']);

App1.config(function($routeProvider){
    //alert("pre-config");
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            template: '<h1>main page</h1>',
            controller: 'heroCtrl'
        }).
        when('/:heroName', {
            template: '<h1>Hello!</h1>',
            controller: 'detailCtrl'
        }).otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
    //alert("post-config");
});

App1.controller('heroCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.heroes = [
     {"name":"Yan Xu", "Role":"Ranger", "Metamorphosis":"Ancient Dragon","desc":"Main Hero"},
     {"name":"Sandria Dettorox", "Role":"Mage", "Metamorphosis":"Diviner","desc":"Main Heroine"},
     {"name":"Schneider Lain", "Role":"Necromancer","Metamorphosis":"None","desc":"Main Villain"}
    ];

    $scope.sortField = 'name';
});

App1.controller('detailCtrl',function($scope, $routeParams){
    console.log("called");
    console.log($routeParams);
});
```

I implemented some list sorting with the first controller it worked correctly.
Yet when I tried to access the route from index.html#/heroName, it did not show the template, did not alert, nor did it log the information in the console. Can anyone tell me what could be wrong here? My angular version is 1.4.7.

Edit:
The HTML Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular-route.min.js"></</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body ng-view>
    <h1>Angular Test</h1>

    <div id="Module1" ng-app="App1" class="col-sm-12">
        <form action="">
            <div ng-controller="heroCtrl">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Role</th>
                            <th>Metamorphosis</th>
                            <th>Character</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="hero in heroes | filter:filter | orderBy:sortField">
                            <td>{{hero.name}}</td>
                            <td>{{hero.Role}}</td>
                            <td>{{hero.Metamorphosis}}</td>
                            <td>{{hero.desc}}</td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <input name="filter" ng-model="filter"></input><br/>
                <a class="btn" ng-click="sortField='name'">Sort By Name</a>
                <a class="btn" ng-click="sortField='Metamorphosis'">Sort By Morph</a>
                <p>Current sort field: {{sortField}}</p>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>


    <div id="Module2">


    </div>
    <script src="Angular/frontPage.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you precise *"when I tried to access the route from index.htm#/heroName"*? You tried from the browser address bar by adding the exact string `#/heroName` to the address?

Comment: @MichaelP.Bazos Yes that is what I did. I typed in the browser address bar and type: index.html#/heroName

Comment: try index.html/#/heroName

Comment: @curiousgeek I tried it but it will lead to a "page not found" error.

Comment: @Griffith I don't think it is related. The html is just a table displaying the data from heroCtrl.

Comment: I just tried in plnkr assuming there's nothing wrong with the html. It works fine. See this : http://plnkr.co/edit/HHNNf17UpgS5QZLoDVZR?p=preview

Comment: You could omit the name of the home page as web servers are usually configured to look for usual names like *index.html, index.htm, ...* It's by the way not clear how your home is named as in the description you wrote *index.htm* but in comment you speak about *index.html*

Comment: You should show the index.html;)

Comment: @MichaelP.Bazos Thank you, it is html#/heroName, just figured out there should be a "ng-view" nested inside the ng-app. The tutorial I was using did not show me that, that is why I am not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be wrong because the home page is not in the description, but I'm guessing that in the home page, you are missing `ng-view` directive.

Thus the template can't be injected. You should have something like that:

```
<body ng-view></body>
```

or, if you have some elements already under the `body` tag:

```
<body>
    <div ng-view></div>
    ...
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, it turned out it is missing an ng-view. :)

Comment: Saw the edit, you should remove everything under `ng-view`. It will be replaced anyway by the router.

Comment: Thanks, just changed it.